# Separate matches in one query

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have nodes labeled 'Group' and only some of them have relationships with people. T

```
GroupA {}, GroupB{personA, personB}, GroupC{}
```

I want to get all the groups and members that have groups assigned to them but I can only figure out to get groups with members

```
Match (:Client {value:'1234'})-[:IDENTIFIES]->(a)<-[r:PART_OF*]-(b:Group)
<-[:BELONGS_TO]-(per:Person)
```

Even if I put a separate Match with a UNION I'm not able to get both the empty groups and membered groups. It says column names have to be same. I'm probably doing something wrong.

Any help?? Thanks!!

Comment: Please add your full query with the union clause. The columns returned in both statements using union must be identical.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query should do what you want. The `per` value in a result row will be `null` if the `b` Group has no  `Person` belonging to it. You can play around with this query [using this console link](http://console.neo4j.org/r/ggpar9).

```
MATCH (:Client {value:'1234'})-[:IDENTIFIES]->(a)<-[r:PART_OF*]-(b:Group)
OPTIONAL MATCH (b)<-[:BELONGS_TO]-(per:Person)
RETURN DISTINCT a, b, per;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
MATCH (c:Client {value: 1234})-[:IDENTIFIES]->(a)<-[r:PART_OF*]-(b:Group)<-[:BELONGS_TO]-             (per:Person), (g:Group) 
RETURN per, b, g
```

This is assuming that you're ok with a duplication in the results in terms of the groups that are displayed.  It also depends on how you want the results returned/displayed (e.g. you may want to use COLLECT).  It might be a bit awkward to iterate through the "Member" results when each row contains all groups.

If you want just empty groups, maybe try something like:

```
MATCH (g:Group)
WHERE NOT g--()
RETURN g
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Your query did get all the information I needed BUT I needed to get groups that belong to that specific client and to sort through that duplication would have been quite much and the answer @cybersam gave using 'optional match' did the trick. Thank you.

Comment: Glad it and he helped. I wasn't sure about the data model as far as groups and clients were related plus all of group's relationships. I also wasn't sure about the "client" thing as it appeared in your original Cypher statement but not in the problem description. Best of luck in the future.

Comment: I'll try to be more verbose about the query, next time! Basically we have multiple clients in our graphdb and we differentiate clusters of graph by their parent Id (client) and have groups that are part of that client and people within that client who belong to those groups. Hope that made sense. Ha ha.